# Efficiently using ZeroMQ sockets in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, zeromq

I am working on multithreading project and I am using [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) socket to send the data as a byte array. Below is my example which works fine. I'm opting for code review to see whether it can be improved by adding a wrapper class for using ZeroMQ socket as some sort of socket manager.

```
public class TestDriver {
    private static final int THREADS = 5;
    private static final long DURATION_OF_RUN = 10;
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long endTime = startTime + (DURATION_OF_RUN * 60 * 1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
                executor.submit(new ClientTask(endTime));
            }

            // wait for termination
            executor.shutdown();

            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And below is `ClientTask` class -

```
public class ClientTask implements Runnable {

    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final String CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    private final long endTime;

    public ClientTask(long endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
            // does the way I am using ZeroMQ socket here is efficient?
            // or we should make connection pooling of sockets using zeromq
            // inside any singleton wrapper class?
            ZMQ.Socket socket = SocketsManager.getInstance().getSockets();

            byte[] byteArray = generateRandomStringAsBytes(20);

            ZMsg req = new ZMsg();
            req.add(byteArray);
            req.send(socket);

            socket.close();
            context.term();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple method which will generate random string and return as bytes
     * 
     * @param length
     * @return
     */
    public static byte[] generateRandomStringAsBytes(int length) {
        return generateRandomString(length).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

And below is my SocketManager class -

```
public class SocketsManager {

    private ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    private static Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());

    private static class SocketsHolder {
        static final SocketsManager INSTANCE = new SocketsManager();
    }

    public static SocketsManager getInstance() {
        return SocketsHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private SocketsManager() {
        // should I do anything here?
    }

    // does below method is right?
    public Socket getSockets() {
        ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.PUSH);
        String identity = String.format("%04X-%04X", rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt());
        socket.setIdentity(identity.getBytes());
        socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5700");

        return socket;
    }
}
```

Is the way I am using `ZeroMQ` socket is efficient here? Or do I need to create connection pool of sockets?

As far as I know `ZeroMQ` sockets **must** be used on the threads where it has been created and I believe one `ZeroMQ` context is usually enough for the application? I read the [ZeroMq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) and I stumbled upon the following:

> First, do not try to use the same socket from multiple threads. Please
>   don't explain why you think this would be excellent fun, just please
>   don't do it. Next, you need to shut down each socket that has ongoing
>   requests. The proper way is to set a low LINGER value (1 second), and
>   then close the socket. If your language binding doesn't do this for
>   you automatically when you destroy a context, I'd suggest sending a
>   patch.
>
> Finally, destroy the context. This will cause any blocking receives or
>   polls or sends in attached threads (i.e., which share the same
>   context) to return with an error. Catch that error, and then set
>   linger on, and close sockets in that thread, and exit. Do not destroy
>   the same context twice. The zmq_ctx_destroy in the main thread will 
>   block until all sockets it knows about are safely closed.

Am I following the above rules in my above code? If not, then how can I achieve the above thing in my code? Since this is my first time working with sockets directly so not able to understand what is the right way to add a wrapper around `ZeroMQ` socket.

Do I need to create connection pool of sockets? As in this [example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:hwclient) they are using same socket connection for same thread to send the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only sending one `ZMsg` per connection.  Establishing TCP connections is generally considered to be a high-overhead operation.  If done over a network, it would involve a [three-way handshake to connect and a two-way handshake to disconnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment).  When done on localhost, the TCP protocol is still somewhat complex, even though the transmission latency is nearly small.

Compare that to this [example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:asyncsrv), which reuses the same connection for multiple messages.

I can understand disconnecting if you have nothing to transmit for a while.  However, if you are trying to push as many messages as possible in a tight loop, it makes no sense to make a new connection per message — it defeats the advantage of using ZeroMQ rather than raw TCP in the first place.